# Bootstrap Datepicker not working, datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker, bootstrap-modal

i am new to bootstrap, i am trying to implement bootstrap date picker, but somehow it is not happening. Can you please check which code of mine is going wrong. below is my .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing the DateTimepicker scripts please include this scripts

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

and you can just go through the demo  http://code.runnable.com/UmOlOZbXvZRqAABU/bootstrap-datepicker-example-text-input-with-specifying-date-format2

Answer (score 0):

somehow i got the work around.. but still it has some issues with time, if anyone has a better solution please post it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

to this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

---

**Reason:**

Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does.
 In order to avoid conflicts, you need to specify the library alias of `$` which in jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`.